# jquery tree traversal to place the error message in the correct place

Tags: jquery, css, dom

I am using a time entry widget found [here](http://keith-wood.name/timeEntry.html) and the default jquery form validation library found [here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).  I have set up my form validator to place error messages in a custom span that follows the form element.  For example:

```
<input type="text" id="event_title" name="event_title" class="required" size="50" maxlength="150" />
<span class="error_ctr"></span>
```

This works fine with the exception of the time entry widget which looks like this when the widget is created.

```
<span class="timeEntry_wrap">
   <input type="text" class="required hasTimeEntry" size="11" value="" name="start_time" id="start_time">
   </span><span class="error_ctr">
</span>
```

The reason is because the time entry widget wraps the input element in a span and the jquery validation tries to find the first span after the input element with a class of error_ctr.  Here is the code I am using to tell the validation plugin where to place the error message:

```
$(".request_form").validate({
    errorElement: "div",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {          
                       error.appendTo( element.nextAll(".error_ctr:first") );
                    }
});
```

How to tell jquery to place the error message in the correct place?

Comment: I'm checking the plugin pages to understand them....Could you point to the specific documentation part of the validation plugin which you've used?

Comment: The timeinput widget is using default settings. ie: `$('#start_time').timeEntry({ timeSteps: [1, 15, 0], spinnerImage: '', show24Hours: true, beforeShow: customRange });` as far as the form validation you can find it [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).

Comment: What element is the validate plugin selecting for the time entry widget, `#start_time`? Also, does the rendered HTML really have the `</span><span>` tags backwards like in your example?

Comment: Correct it is selecting `#start_time`. They are not backwards in the rendered html or in my example (although I can see why you would say that). `</span><span class="error_ctr">` the first `</span>` closes the `timeEntry_wrap` found at the top. Sorry it is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
error.appendTo( element.closest(".timeEntry_wrap").andSelf().next(".error_ctr") );
```

note: updated after @pimvdb's feedback

Comment: This will add every element on the page that is a parent of anything.

Comment: This works very well.  Thanks for the answer! I found out that this also works: `error.appendTo(element.parent("span.timeEntry_wrap").nextAll(".error_ctr:first") );`

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
...
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    if (element.id == "start_time") {
        $("+ .error_ctr", element.parent()).html(error);
    } else {
        error.appendTo( element.nextAll(".error_ctr:first") );
    }
}
...
```

Comment: This also works very well. I ended up finding another solution and posted that code in response to iC3b3rg's post.  Thanks!